# How can I use a SUMPRODUCT to get a weighted average but only if a cell has a value above zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have figured I have done something wrong because I can't seem to get the statement to work.

So, I have this:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit],Purchases_XYZ[Cost])/SUM(Purchases_XYZ[Cost]),"")
```

This gives me a weighted average and I am happy with this.

But what if I have removed some of these purchases (I may have sold some stock or similar). So in this case, the "cost" cell is deleted and left blank. I am not even sure I need the "IFERROR" anymore either. Before I was just doing a straight average but I really need a weighted average.

So if the Cost cell = 0 then I don't want to count that in the weighted average. But if the Cost cell > 0 then count it in the weighted average.

Unless you can think of another way around this where I can leave the cost in and if I move the stock around, it won't be counted toward the weighted average. Because the way I am doing it right now is clumsy. I am deleting the cell and just adding a comment with the price purchased.

Notes: I am using Excel from Office 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a conditional check that meets your needs and convert it from true false to 1 or 0.  Use the formula below and adjust ranges to suit your needs.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B6>0),B2:B6,A2:A6)/SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B6>0),B2:B6)
```

[image: POC]

Comment: Thank you!!! 

I just solved this too similarly:



=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit],--(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit]<>0),Purchases_XYZ[Cost])/SUMPRODUCT(Purchases_XYZ[Cost],--(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit]<>0)),"")

Comment: The only problem is I need to copy this formula to 30 sheets with each having a unique table name. How do I do it quicker?

Comment: Technically speaking I don't think you need to add the comparison operation in the denominator since its 0 that you are excluding.  It doesn't do much harm either though.

Comment: Separate Question

Comment: I did the comparison exactly as you said... because it does no harm :)