# How can I set up a weighted average of purchase price for something that I might sell part amounts of?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a weighted average set up like this:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit],Purchases_XYZ[Cost])/SUM(Purchases_XYZ[Cost]),"")
```

The full table includes:
Purchases_XYZ[Date], Purchases_XYZ[Cost], Purchases_XYZ[Units], Purchases_XYZ[Cost Per Unit], Purchases_XYZ[Extras], Purchases_XYZ[Location]

But what if I sell 30% of my units at Location "b"? Then I need to manually decrease the number of units I have left at Location "b".

What if I sell all the units at Location "d"? Then my weighted average can no longer be counted because there is no longer any of that unit left at that price.

I can do the manual stuff - that wouldn't be impossible. But I feel like I am making more work than it needs to be. If you have solutions to offer, I am keen to hear how it could be done.

Comment: So calculate the amount or value of the stock and also the value of revenue.

Comment: So how can I do a sumproduct of all the rows then if at some stage I empty a "Cost Per Unit" cell? So that the sumproduct doesn't count rows that have a 0 cost per unit.

Comment: Isn't this a [repeat of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138178/how-can-i-use-a-sumproduct-to-get-a-weighted-average-but-only-if-a-cell-has-a-va)?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was an oversight. At first I didn't realise I had published the other question. Changed my mind and went here... then realised I needed the other question... long story short. I did repeat accidentally.